# Need a name and statistics for a mental illness

Tags: psychology

Back when I was a kid, despite horror movies, the most terrifying moment that's stuck with me from fiction wasn't from a horror movie, but from "A Wrinkle in Time." It was a scene to where many children walked out from their front doors simultaneously, all dressed identically to the rest of their gender, the boys all bouncing basketballs in unison and the girls all jumping ropes in unison. That scene stuck with me, and ever since I've preferred if there's at least a little disorder in things. Like if I'm organizing books in a series, rather than keep them perfectly in order, I may switch the seven and the nine book. It's uncommon that I do it, but it's basically about the same if someone sets up something and then tries to make it symmetrical... just in reverse.

However, I know that the desire for symmetry and order to the extreme can manifest as an OCD personality.

I'm wondering what a full disorder version of this 'avoid perfect order' inclination might look like, and ways it could manifest? Does such a thing exist already? I'm not talking "everything must be messy" but an intense desire that *all* things must contain at least a little disorder, variety, or artistry. Like if all the streetlamps on the character's home street were the same color, he'd sneak out in the middle of the night and change one of them to a different color, or if all the other houses are white, he might hire a muralist to make his home a giant portrait.

I'm considering a comedic short story of such an individual and a traditional OCD individual being at odds with one another (likely in an HOA or roommate setting).

So the questions are:

1. Does such a disorder already exist? (If so, what's it called? If not, what *should* it be called?)
2. What are some potential ways it would manifest itself?
3. What are some of the things that would most negatively impact the individual?

Comment: The way you worded your points (2) and (3) will hurt the chances of your thread being kept open, especially since this kind of comedy fell out of fashion sometime in the 80ies anywhere but in Germany I believe. If the illness does exist, I think you are fine, but if it doesn't, you are asking for pure idea generation. Mental illnesses do not behave according to rules, extrapolation is impossible. Nothing in everyday life is perfectly ordered, what your protagonist feels is "too ordered" and how well he can cope is completely up to you. I would suggest rephrasing them so they can be answered.

Comment: So basically just a fear of absolute order?

Comment: If it doesn't already have a name, I propose OMD, for the [Oscar Madison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Odd_Couple) Disorder.

Comment: After doing research nothing resembling came up. This seems to be an imaginary psychological disorder. Perhaps similar to OCD, but obsessively disarranging things. Possible names include Chaotic OCD, or maximum entropy disorder (my inner physicist like that), or obsessional chaos. @HenryTaylor deserves a tip of the hat for his Oscar Madison Disorder. Generally OCD seems to spring from anxiety about chaotic & fearful thinking in its sufferers. This could be its inverse.

Comment: Sorry, but I feel that this is asking for too much at once. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @Raditz_35 A lot of 80's stuff is making a comeback, to be fair, and like I said, due to my own experiences, a part of me suspected it might exist as a disorder. It's more about trying to accurately build actions/responses of characters.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling How too broad? It's dealing with specifically one potential mental disorder that would be a very niche case.

Comment: @JustSnilloc Pretty much, yea. Kind of a desire to make things not fully mathmatically predictable or similar.

Comment: @liljoshu You are asking three (admittedly related) questions. (1) seems to require an expert in neuroscience to answer properly; your side question there looks opinion-based, with many potentially equally valid answers. (2) and (3) depend heavily on the specifics of the disease and how they interact with the individual, as discussed in previous comments, and as such could be either opinon-based, broad, or character-based, all three of which are valid reasons to close a question.

Comment: You might make a better start by doing some more reading on OCD ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tongyiphobia** is the fear of sameness. I found zero info online other than the word itself.

**Apeirophobia** is the fear of eternity but is often used to mean a fear of infinite repetition, however a sufferer will counterintuitively make their lives as *predictable* as possible (probably a symptom of any phobia is to avoid unfamiliar situations that might lead to a triggering episode).

**[Anticonformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticonformity_(psychology))** is the urge to go against groupthink, while **[Reactance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactance_(psychology))** is a defense mechanism against feeling pressured to conform. The wiki link claims **Reactance** (when a test subject became more defiant after a disagreement) occurred in 8% of test subjects involved in a highly artificial scenario where a confederate is deliberately lying.

Artificial conformity studies like the [**Asch Conformity Experiments**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asch_conformity_experiments) are designed to test group *compliance* and the results are often *overstated* in pop psychology (not to mention test subjects are typically teenage college students not representative of general society). [**Milgram's Obedience Expiriments** have been called into question for unscientific (loaded) situations where researchers badgered test subjects to comply](http://boingboing.net/2013/09/11/revisiting-milgrams-obedienc.html). I doubt you will find any hard statistics on anti-conformity outside cultural opinion op-eds (for example comparing very generalized non-conformist behavior in the US vs China).

**[Oppositional Defiant Disorder (ODD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppositional_defiant_disorder)** is an anti-social behavior in children, but it seems to be more about disruption than anti-conformity.

Some marketing folklore claims that customers will feel compelled to answer "yes" after saying "no" a number of times, typically after three or four "no" answers. I found a few articles boasting this claim online but nothing resembling legitimate research. It is probably just a management lie to encourage sellers to be persistent.

Comment: Having a name, I think I know some people at a school I could ask about Tongyiphobia... it sounds vaguely familiar, I'll ask about it. Thanks!